# How do I filter and delete specific objects in the database? | React as Front and Rails as Back/API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, database

So, here is the thing, I'm learning React right now, and I'm building a small taskmanager webapp with React as frontend and Rails(API) as Backend to pratice using React with Rails(which I'm already used to build other webapps with).
The tasks are objects in the database which have a "title" as a string, and "done" as a boolean to indicated if they're done or not.
Using `async` and `await fetch('')` I managed to create functions to be able to pass methods directly to the database to check and uncheck the tasks as done, and also delete the tasks. Like that, for example:

```
async deleteTask(task) {
            if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete: "${task.title}"`)) {
                await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/tasks/${task.id}`, {method: 'DELETE'});
                this.props.loadTasks();
            }
        }
```

Now I want to create a function to delete ALL of the done tasks at once. How would I do that? How do I take all of the tasks and filter them by "done == true" or something like that and pass a DELETE method to the database?
Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated! I tried many alternatives, even tried something like that, no sucess:

```
async deleteAllDoneTasks() {
      if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete all done tasks?`)) {
          await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/tasks/)`, {method: 'DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE done = 1'});
          this.props.loadTasks();
      }
    }
```

EDIT¹: So, according to JMadelaine this can't be made by the frontend. How do I do that in Rails then? And how do I call that in React, make it happen when I press a button?
I commented below what I would do first. I'd appreciate any insight, help, or solutions. Thanks :)

Comment: This is not the responsibility of your front end React app. Your Rails server should have an endpoint called "delete all  done tasks" or something similar, and all you front end does is call that endpoint. It doesnt make sense to have to figure out all the ids on the front end, because deleting the tasks has nothing to do with a specific id. it is to do with the done status.

Comment: Then I would need to create a method in the Tasks Controller like...
"Task.where(done: true).destroy_all", right?
But would I also need a custom route? And how do I call that in the React frontend when pressing a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need a custom route for this action as it is not default CRUD action.
So in the `routes.rb` under the `tasks` route add custom route like:

```rb
delete 'tasks', to: 'tasks#multiple_delete'
```

Then in `TasksController` define `multiple_delete` method with code inside which will delete desired `tasks` and return answer to your client, something like:

```rb
def multiple_delete
  ::Task.where(done: true).destroy_all
  head :ok
end
```

and then in your React, according to answer from server you can do some things.

Then go to your React code, on desired button add `onClick` event (I do not know which framework you use, I will share example of Shopify code which I am familiar with.
outside the `render()` do:

```js
deleteAllDoneTasks = () => {
      if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete all done tasks?`)) {
          await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/tasks)`, {method: 'DELETE'})
      }
}
```

inside the `render()` do:

```
<Button onClick={this.deleteAllDoneTasks}>
```

Comment: Thank you, Roman! I just had to add a new line after your "await fetch" line, before closing the `if`, to let React reloads the state of the tasks automatically. I'll post it here just so it may help someone else in the future. I did something like that:
`this.props.loadTasks();`
Which was a call to another function:
`async loadTasks() {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/tasks');
        const tasks = await response.json();
        this.setState({ tasks: tasks });
    }`

Comment: Btw, what does the ‘head :ok‘ means/do? The rest I'm familiar with

Comment: head :ok returns 200 http code without body, only success code. However you can return whatever you want, if you use rails server as api you can do something like `return json: { message: 'All completed tasks have been successfully deleted' }, status: :ok` and show this message to the user inside your promise. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)